# Mirroring User Controls in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some user controls that do not support `RightToLeft` Layout and I have the DLLs only.
I want implement `RightToLeft` Layout in these controls by code.

How can I do that?

Note : I try to use `TableLayoutPanel` and `FlowLayoutPanel`, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it manually using some logic.

```
private bool isLeft = true;
private void SwapPosition()
{
   isLeft = !isLeft;
   foreach (Control cnt in this.Controls)
       SwapPosition(cnt);
}
private void SwapPosition(Control cnt)
{
    cnt.Left = cnt.Parent.Width - (cnt.Left + cnt.Width);
    ///Assign other properties also
    ///ie. cnt.RightToLeft = !isLeft
    ///if (isLeft) then NormalFont else Hebrew or any
    foreach (Controls cntChild in cnt.Controls)
        RightToLeft(cntChild);
}
```